# How to find out what SQL queries are being blocked and what's blocking them?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, optimization, blocking

I'm trying to optimize some slow web pages, and my guess is that the problem has to do with SQL blocking (doesn't seem to be a matter of CPU or I/O utilization on the web server or database server). What's the quickest way to find out what queries are getting blocked and what queries are doing the blocking?

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT
    p1.SPID AS blockedSPID, p2.SPID AS blockingSPID, ...
FROM 
    master..sysprocesses p1
    JOIN
    master..sysprocesses p2 ON p1.blocked = p2.spid
```

Remus: Activity monitor may time out under server load with error 1222

The [MS KB 224453](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224453) has a lot of good stuff

Comment: @KM How about next time, edit the answer and correct it...?  Thanks.

Comment: @KM: or master..sysprocesses or master.sys.sysprocesses If you omit the schema, it works on SQL 2000+ plus

Answer (score 4):

[Activity Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879320.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[How to monitor blocking in SQL Server 2005 and in SQL Server 2000](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271509)

A very nice Blog post here:

[Getting Blocking Info In SQL Server 2005 & 2008 the easy way](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dannyr/archive/2008/10/07/getting-blocking-info-in-sql-server-2005-amp-2008-the-easy-way.aspx)