# Intermittent SQL timeouts

Tags: sql-server-2005, timeout

Since a few days ago, the SQL server (Microsoft SQL Server 2005) backing our site has started occasionally timeouting. It is happening at seemingly random times approximately every hour or two. It usually takes about 10 minutes during which we see hundreds of timeouted requests. Under normal circumstances, most of our queries take less than 50ms. A query which takes a significant fraction of a second is an exception.

I have effectively killed a day trying to figure out at least something without any real progress. Normally, the server load is about 10-20%, and when the timeouts happen, we don’t see any increased CPU load. Also, there is nothing special happening during the timeouts; no overzealous web crawler, no heavy background tasks, no increased network traffic, no increased number of connections etc. Simply, everything looks as usual.

Not making any progress, we decided to restart it (and install the latest SP since we were in it) which seems to have fixed the problem. It has been already over six hours without any incident. Also, the CPU load has gone down under 10%.

It almost seems like if the SQL server "deteriorated" overtime. Perhaps, some internal structure (some cache or statistic) got out shape and caused the occasional problems. I don’t have any other explanation.

The only thing I noticed when I was monitoring the server (and got lucky once to be present when the timeouts were happening), I saw several long running queries waiting on CXPACKET. But I learned that this is most likely just a consequence of some other problem. I wrote a script monitoring SQL requests, and so hopefully, next time it happens, I will have more information.

Has anybody had similar experience? I’m not an SQL Server guru. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I just voted to move this to serverfault - a good DBA or server admin should be able to help with this. That said - have you looked at transactions running on the server (any open serialized transactions?) have you used sp_lock and sp_who to see locks and processes, to see if it is a locking issue? And have you left profiler running on the system to give more information when the issue reoccurs?

Comment: The script I wrote basically monitors sys.dm_exec_requests and sys.dm_exec_sessions and looks for blocking requests. However, it was only after we restarted the server and it seems it is not going to happen again. Before, I was trying to use Activity Monitor, but it was too slow and cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

since everything looked normal: CPU, nothing special happening, no overzealous web crawler, no heavy background tasks, no increased network traffic, no increased number of connections etc. I'd look into locking\blocking\race condition.  Use this to see what (if anything) is locking when the time-out are happening:

[How to find out what SQL queries are being blocked and what's blocking them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291220/how-to-find-out-what-sql-queries-are-being-blocked-and-whats-blocking-them/2291257#2291257)